# How write in console attribute data?

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 buttons. How i can write in concole her attibute data?

```
<button onClick={this.consoleData} data="atr-1">atr1</button>
<button onClick={this.consoleData} data="atr-2">atr2</button>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, consoleData is a function isn't

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `data-` attribute with `event.target.dataset`, since you have different `data-` attribute, you can get these via `event.target.dataset[Object.keys(event.target.dataset)[0]]`

So the solution is

```
 consoleData=(event)=>{
    console.log(event.target.dataset[Object.keys(event.target.dataset)[0]])
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <button id="v1" onClick={this.consoleData} data-attr1="atr-1">atr1</button>
<button id="v2" onClick={this.consoleData} data-attr2="atr-2">atr2</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Check the stackblitz link,

[Check the stackblitz solution here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ok9gmh)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by targeting the clicked element. This can be done by getting `e.target` in your callback method, and then getting the `data` attribute from it using `.getAttribute()` (see browser console for output rather than snippet console):

```js
const App = () => {
  const consoleData = e => {
    console.log(e.target.getAttribute("data"));
  }
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={consoleData} data="atr-1">atr1</button>
      <button onClick={consoleData} data="atr-2">atr2</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
  
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

However, rather than adding custom attributes like this, you really should add a suffix attribute name to your data attribute. This way you can access it through `dataset`. Below, I have named this custom data attribute `data-attr`, which you can then get the value of by using `e.target.dataset.attr`:

```js
const App = () => {
  const consoleData = e => {
    console.log(e.target.dataset.attr);
  }
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={consoleData} data-attr="atr-1">atr1</button>
      <button onClick={consoleData} data-attr="atr-2">atr2</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
  
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```